# Control spacing of CheckBoxGroup in a form table in an Xpage

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

My app has a checkBoxGroup inside of a Form Layout Row and that is inside of a Form table.

I want to control the font weight and spacing and so on, it seems I can't. If the checkbox group is outside the form table, my css works, but not inside the form table. I believe this is because the table that is generated by the form layout table is not getting changed. I want to change ONLY the spacing inside of this on form row.

Here is the code for the checkbox *inside* the form layout row:

```
<xe:formRow id="formRow4"
                            labelPosition="inherit" label="Area">
                            <xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup2"
                                layout="pageDirection" styleClass="threeColumnCheckBoxGroup"
                                style="font-size:8pt;font-style:normal">
                                <xp:selectItems>
                                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var tmp:String = viewScope.application;
var tmpLst = []; 

if (tmp == "OTM")
{
tmpLst.push("User Interface");
tmpLst.push("Rating/Planning");
tmpLst.push("Tendering/Booking");
tmpLst.push("Documentton");
tmpLst.push("Finance");
}

if (tmp = "GTM")
{
tmpLst.push("Parting Screening");
tmpLst.push("AES Filing");
tmpLst.push("AMS Filing");
tmpLst.push("Product Classification");
}

return tmpLst}]]></xp:this.value>
                                </xp:selectItems>
                            </xp:checkBoxGroup>
                        </xe:formRow>
```

And for the checkbox outside:

```
<xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup4" layout="pageDirection" styleClass="threeColumnCheckBoxGroup" style="font-size:8pt;font-style:normal">
                                <xp:selectItems>
                                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var tmp:String = viewScope.application;
var tmpLst = []; 

if (tmp == "OTM")
{
tmpLst.push("User Interface");
tmpLst.push("Rating/Planning");
tmpLst.push("Tendering/Booking");
tmpLst.push("Documentton");
tmpLst.push("Finance");
}

if (tmp = "GTM")
{
tmpLst.push("Parting Screening");
tmpLst.push("AES Filing");
tmpLst.push("AMS Filing");
tmpLst.push("Product Classification");
}

return tmpLst}]]></xp:this.value>
                                </xp:selectItems>
                            </xp:checkBoxGroup
```

and the css

```
.xspCheckBox { width: 500px; /* change to your preferred width */ }
.xspCheckBox td { white-space: nowrap; padding-bottom:3px; }


.threeColumnCheckboxGroup { display: inline; }
.threeColumnCheckboxGroup td { float: left; width: 24%; padding-bottom:3px; }
```

Comment: Have you checked the HTML output to see what class it puts on things inside the form table?

Comment: There's a typo in your example code styleClass="threeColumnCheckBoxGroup" vs .threeColumnCheckboxGroup

Comment: This looks to be something that will rely entirely on how the generated output behaves in the DOM. There's likely some specifics from the default CSS getting in the way.